# WebRTC: strange encode bitrate when using openh264

Tags: encoding, webrtc, h.264

- I have succeed integrate openh264 to webrtc APP demo(Android
  platform), However the video quality is not good as VP8.
- I check the bitrate of two mobile phone and found that one phone have
  nomal encode bitrate(400kbps-1500kbps for 640x480 frame) and encoded
  frame received in another phone have good quality, while another
  phone have abnormal bitrate(only ~30kbps for 640x480 frame) which
  result that encoded frame received in another phone is have very bad
  quality.
- I check the encode time and decode time and frame rate, it seems that encoder 
  and decoder can processing the video with no problem(encode time for one
  frame is about 20ms, decode time for one frame is about 10ms, and frame rate 
  is about 30).
- Can some one tell me which result the strange encode bitrate?

Comment: Is the hardware powerful enough? Did you try to put bitrate limits in SDP exchange?

Comment: @fycth,
1.  currently VP8 and OpenH264 both using software Encode/Decode, from profile, they have similar performance. So I think hardware is not the cause of strange encode bitrate of OpenH264. 
2. I don't know how to limits the SDP exchange,  will it has influence on encode bitrate?

Comment: regarding the second question: you can inject bandwidth limits (separate for data, video and audio) into SDP during the connection init. Not sure if it would affect your case, but it affects browsers at least. For example, if you establish WebRTC connection with no limits in SDP, audio channel will take low kbit/s value. If you explicitly set audio bandwidth limit to say 320 kbit/s, it will take whole 320 kbit/s limit. So, not sure, but might be reasonable to try using explicit bandwidth limits.

Comment: Hi @Fisher, I am also working on a similar project to integrate openH264 for webRTC Android app. Can you throw some lights on how can I integrate the built libraries with the appRTC? Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

@fycth, thanks for your advice.

The Problem has been resolved. Reason for strange bitrate is that One mobile phone using HardWare H264 Encoder/Decoder, while the bitrate & frame rate control is not that well. Now I force the mobile to use SoftWare Encoder/Decoder, bitrate become normal.